# Live data is put inside of columns (making a dataset) but does not update when I use pd.merge, it only occurs on one row

Tags: python, pandas, merge, spyder

I am working on a project which involves python 3.9, the code collects live data from the sensors and builds a new dataset, I then try to update the data set and all goes well, untill I come up with the `pd.merge` , this only allows a single row to be merged onto one random row of the live data mitigating the res,  and does not update for the whole dataset.
I have the necessary part of the code written below.

```
 colnames=['Redundant','AcX', 'AcY', 'AcZ', 'FSR A', 'FSR B']
 test_data_pre=pd.read_csv('live_data.csv',names=colnames, header=None)
 test_data_pre1 = test_data_pre['AcX'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace("'", ""))
 test_data_pre2 = pd.merge(test_data_pre,test_data_pre1)
```

I will be tagging some pictures of the variable explorer so that to become clear what issue i am having

[image: Here is the live data coming in from the sensors]

I am trying to edit the 2nd column from the left, and merging it again with this data

[image: Here is the edited version of that 2nd column]

[image: This is the issue I am having when I use the last line of my code]

```
1654149216  b'1652      2204    -15924  0          0'
1654149284  b'1572      2188    -15664  0          0'
1654149285  b'1732      2128    -15764  0          0'
1654149285  b'1656      2224    -15904  0          0'
1654149286  b'1508      2144    -15660  0          0'
1654149286  b'1592      2240    -15676  0          0'
1654149287  b'1572      2096    -15804  0          0'
1654149287  b'1556      2328    -15956  0          0'
1654149288  b'1604      2304    -15704  0          0'
1654149288  b'1500      2268    -15628  0          0'
1654149289  b'1572      2252    -15960  0          0'
1654149289  b'1532      2100    -15852  0          0'
1654149290  b'1640      2184    -15808  0          0'
1654149290  b'1568      2156    -15568  0          0'
```

Comment: Please provide data as plain text to be reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the line

```
pd.concat([df1, df2],axis=1)
```

Adds the columns in df1 to the end of df2 (rows should be identical)

which helped solve the problem of my dataframe not updating.